# Function to move a SDL2 window while mouse down flickers the window and doesn't move 'fast' enough

Tags: c++, sdl, mouse

I made a function to move an borderless SDL window.  I use `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to 'activate' the window movement and `SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP` to 'deactivate' it.  For some reason it does not just move like it should but instead moves way slower than my mouse and flickers if I moved it by a good distance.

I use SDL2, and I'm on windows 10.

My loop always updates my mouse position, and the function takes the mouse position reduces it by the last mouse position and then moves the window by that distance.

```cpp
sPos moveClock(int event){
    sPos temPos = setPos(0,0);
    if(tempMoveVar==1){
        temPos = setPos(gvMousePos.x-mPos.x,gvMousePos.y-mPos.y);
        mPos = setPos(gvMousePos.x,gvMousePos.y);
    }else if(event==-1){    //Mouse Down
        mPos = setPos(gvMousePos.x,gvMousePos.y);
        tempMoveVar=1;
    }
    if(event==-65){         //Mouse Up
        tempMoveVar=0;
    }
    return temPos;
}
```

I just want the window to move 'with' the mouse while my mouse button is down, like you normally can move windows.

Comment: Consider using `SDL_SetWindowHitTest` instead of moving the window manually. Also, I would used named constants instead of hardcoded values for event IDs.

Comment: I cant find a lot about `SDL_SetWindowHitTest` but it sounds like exactly what i´m looking for, however i am not sure how to use it. What to put as `SDL_HitTest callback` and what to put `void*       callback_data` - may you help me to understand or can u provide some tutorial? :)

Comment: Alright, I'll write a full answer.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than moving the window manually, I suggest using [`SDL_SetWindowHitTest`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowHitTest):

```
int SDL_SetWindowHitTest(SDL_Window* window, SDL_HitTest callback, void* callback_data);
```

This function lets you specify what dragging specific pixels of a window does (possible actions are moving the window, resizing it, or doing nothing).

You should probably call this function once, after creating your window.

Parameters are:

- `SDL_Window* window` speaks for itself.
- `SDL_HitTest callback` receives a function that, when given coordinates of a pixel, determines what dragging this pixel does.
- `void* callback_data` is described below.

You need to write a function to pass to `callback`. It has to have following return type and parameter types:

```
SDL_HitTestResult MyCallback(SDL_Window* win, const SDL_Point* area, void* data)
{
    ...
}
```

`area->x` and `area->y` are the coordinates of the pixel that's being checked. `win` is the window.

`data` will receive the same pointer you passed to `callback_data` when calling `SDL_SetWindowHitTest`. You can use this pointer to pass arbitrary data to your callback; or, if you don't need it, simply set it to `0`.

Your callback should return one of the following:

- `SDL_HITTEST_NORMAL` - no action.
- `SDL_HITTEST_DRAGGABLE` - dragging this pixel moves the window.
- `SDL_HITTEST_RESIZE_*` - dragging this pixel resizes a specific edge (or edges) of the window. (Here `*` is one of: `TOPLEFT`, `TOP`, `TOPRIGHT`, `RIGHT`, `BOTTOMRIGHT`, `BOTTOM`, `BOTTOMLEFT`, `LEFT`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this realy helps.
I´m gonna tinker with it a littlebit, so far it moves smothly but does go back to its original position. But i gues i know how to get things finished.
Thanks a lot again.